# Error with import com.google.android.maps.* package from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gradle

Hi guys I have a problem after exported my project from Eclipse to Android studio I have the problem with `import com.google.android.maps.*` package, don't recognise it. I tried a lot of things which I found, but doesn't work for me.

> TouchedLocationOverlay.java

```
package util;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class TouchedLocationOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Handler handler;

    public TouchedLocationOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Handler h) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

        // Handler object instantiated in the class MainActivity
        this.handler = h;
    }

    // Executed, when populate() method is called
    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
        return mOverlays.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate(); // Invokes the method createItem()
    }

    // This method is invoked, when user tap on the map
    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView map) {

        // Creating a Message object to send to Handler
        Message message = new Message();

        // Creating a Bundle object ot set in Message object
        Bundle data = new Bundle();

        // Setting latitude in Bundle object
        data.putInt("latitude", p.getLatitudeE6());

        // Setting longitude in the Bundle object
        data.putInt("longitude", p.getLongitudeE6());

        // Setting the Bundle object in the Message object
        message.setData(data);

        // Sending Message object to handler
        handler.sendMessage(message);

        return super.onTap(p, map);
    }
}
```

> gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':google-play-services_lib')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: This is all Google Maps V1 stuff, that's the problem.  Just update the code to use Google Maps V2 API, it's actually way easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in the `dependencies` section of your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

You don't need to add a `.jar` to your `libs` folder.

More Info [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: I did it but got the same problem again, don't find this 
`import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;`

Comment: Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Error:(10, 31) error: package com.google.android.maps does not exist

Comment: Try Doing right-click Properties->Android and selecting a Target Name Google APIs instead of Android x.x fixed it

Comment: In Android Studio ? I did this in Eclipse, there is no errors there, but after export and open it in Android Studio there is this problem.

Comment: No, `play-services` is the the fat jar. No, `3.2` is very old. Make sure you download the Google Play Repository via the Android SDK manager.